# Issue with date and time value - Lists in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to make "date and time" column in SharePoint so it will behave in this way:

-if date that is entered in that column is today, tomorrow that column will be empty.

To explain it a lil' bit better, lets put it this way:

That column is reservation column. User enters the date on which he will stop doing something:

column_1-column_2-column_3-RESERVATION_COLUMN

If today is 01.01.2012, and I will be doing something till 05.01.2012., I will enter "05.01.2012." in RESERVATION_COLUMN". When that day comes, or the day after it (isn't really mather) that column will be empty.

I tried some ways, but I didn't succeed. Any help?

Thanks in advance,
K.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of is using a workflow.

Using workflow -> Wait till day + 1 then Set field value to blank.

Comment: cannot try it now, will try it tomorrow morning and post results. Thanks for response :)

Comment: Hmmm. As I know, workflows only triggers on some action or manually, I cannot trigger them on, lets say, every day 12:00AM... am i right?

Comment: There are Actions , Pause Until and Pause For, in SharePoint designer workflow. You can Do calculation for the Number of Days you want to Pause your workflow for and Pause it for that duration. then set the field value to blank. I've just written it down Step by Step. You can check it here and tell me if it works as I've not tested it yet.
.
http://myviwo.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/performing-action-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow-after-specific-time/

Comment: Thanks, my friend. Will try it first thing monday. Will repost results. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

also you can create TimerJob, which will be executed one or few times per day.
This timer job will query list items with your parameters, like items, where in the date field is value equals today or less then today. Then TimerJob will iterate and update this field.

Other, more difficult way is to write your own custom datatime field with specific behavior.